# Fortran function num2str

Tags: string, function, fortran, numbers

I'm trying to create  function that takes a number and returns a string representation of that number. This is what I've tried:

```
  program test
  print *, num2str(9.0)
  end

  character(len=128) function num2str(num)
     real num
     write(num2str,*) num
  endfunction
```

But this returns the error:

```
num2str.f:1.22:

      print *, num2str(9.0)                                             
                      1
Error: Return type mismatch of function 'num2str' at (1) (INTEGER(4)/CHARACTER(1))
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Add `implicit none` to each scoping unit.

Comment: put your function in a module (foo for instance) and add a use statement (use foo) at the top of the main program. The trouble you meet comes from the fact that num2str definition is not known in the main program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike with subroutines, you need to import or declare the function interface in the `program` scope.

**Option 1**

Explicitly declaring the interface:

```
program test
  interface
     character(len=128) function num2str(num)
       real num
     end function num2str
  end interface
  print *, num2str(9.0)
end

character(len=128) function num2str(num)
  real num
  write(num2str,*) num
endfunction
```

**Option 2**

Put the function into the program `contains` section, which automatically generates the interface:

```
program test
  print *, num2str(9.0)
contains
  character(len=128) function num2str(num)
    real num
    write(num2str,*) num
  endfunction
end
```

**Option 3**

Define the function inside a module and import that module in `program test`:

```
module m
contains
  character(len=128) function num2str(num)
    real num
    write(num2str,*) num
  endfunction num2str
end module m

program test
  use m
  print *, num2str(9.0)
end
```

Comment: And the additional `character(128) num2str`.  An explicit interface, although desirable, is not required.